# Java/J2EE Internal Server Error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a DaoHibernateImpl file which is breaking my application. Here is the code for this and its xml.

```
    public class OfferBankDaoHibernateImpl extends GenericDaoHibernateImpl<OfferBank, Long> implements OfferBankDao {

        static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OfferBankDaoHibernateImpl.class);
        private ResourceManager rMgr = new ResourceManager(this);

        public List<OfferBank> findOfferBankByName(String offerBankNm) throws AppException {
            List<OfferBank> offerBanks = new ArrayList<OfferBank>();
            try {
                // offerBanks =
                // sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(OfferBank.class)
                // .add( Restrictions.eq("offerBankNm", offerBankNm))
                // .list();

                offerBanks = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from OfferBank ob where ob.offerBankNm = '" + offerBankNm + "'").list();
            } catch (GenericJDBCException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new AppException(e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new AppException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return offerBanks;
        }

        public Object[] getOfferBanks(List<String> offerBankTypes, int startPos, int endPos, List<Long> statusIds) {
            int totalRowCount = 1000000;
            try {
                if (endPos == 0) {
                    endPos = totalRowCount;
                }
                String dataSql = rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks");
                dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks_types_where");
                if (!statusIds.isEmpty()) {
                    dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks_status_where");
                }
                dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_banks_get_banks_group_by");

                log.debug("query : " + dataSql);
                SQLQuery dataQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(dataSql);
                if (!statusIds.isEmpty()) {
                    dataQuery.setParameterList("offerBankStatusIds", statusIds);
                }
                dataQuery.setParameterList("offerBankTypes", offerBankTypes).setParameter("start", startPos).setParameter("end", endPos);
                List offerBankList = dataQuery.list();
                return makeOfferBankTO(offerBankList);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                log.error("Error getOfferBanks(List<Long> offerBankTypes ,int startPos, int endPos, List<Long> statusIds)");
                throw e;
            }
        }



        public Object[] getOfferBanksByBanner(List<String> offerBankTypes, int startPos, int endPos, List<Long> statusIds) {
            int totalRowCount = 1000000;
            try {
                if (endPos == 0) {
                    endPos = totalRowCount;
                }
                String dataSql = rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks_by_banner");
                dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks_types_where");
                if (!statusIds.isEmpty()) {
                    dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks_status_where");
                }
                dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_banks_get_banks_by_banner_group_by");

                log.debug("query : " + dataSql);
                SQLQuery dataQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(dataSql);
                if (!statusIds.isEmpty()) {
                    dataQuery.setParameterList("offerBankStatusIds", statusIds);
                }
                dataQuery.setParameterList("offerBankTypes", offerBankTypes).setParameter("start", startPos).setParameter("end", endPos);
                List offerBankList = dataQuery.list();
                return makeOfferBankTO(offerBankList);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                log.error("Error getOfferBanksByBanner(List<Long> offerBankTypes ,int startPos, int endPos, List<Long> statusIds)");
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public Object[] getOfferBankById(List<Long> offerBankIds) {
            int startPos = 1;
            int endPos = 100000;
            String dataSql = rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks");
            dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_get_banks_ids_where");
            dataSql += " " + rMgr.get("sql.offer_banks_get_banks_group_by");
            log.debug("sql= " + dataSql);
            SQLQuery dataQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(dataSql);
            dataQuery.setParameterList("offerBankIds", offerBankIds).setParameter("start", startPos).setParameter("end", endPos);
            List offerBankList = dataQuery.list();
            return makeOfferBankTO(offerBankList);
        }

        private Object[] makeOfferBankTO(List offerBankList) {
            int totalRowCount = 0;
            List<OfferBankTO> offerBankTOs = new ArrayList<OfferBankTO>();
            Iterator iter = offerBankList.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Object[] row = (Object[]) iter.next();
                OfferBankTO ob = new OfferBankTO();
                ob.setOfferBankId(((BigDecimal) row[0]).longValue());
                ob.setPromotionalPeriodId(((BigDecimal) row[1]).longValue());
                ob.setOfferBankName(row[2].toString());
                ob.setOfferBankStatusDesc(row[3].toString());
                if (row[4] != null) {
                    ob.setStartDate(DateFormats.dateFmt.format((Date) row[4]));
                }
                if (row[5] != null) {
                    ob.setEndDate(DateFormats.dateFmt.format((Date) row[5]));
                }
                ob.setOfferBankTypeDesc(row[6].toString());
                ob.setOfferBankTypeCd(row[7].toString());
                ob.setPromotionalPeriodNm(row[8].toString());
                ob.setTotalCount(((Integer) row[9]).intValue());
                ob.setEditingCount(((Integer) row[10]).intValue());
                ob.setFailedDeactiveCount(((Integer) row[11]).intValue());
                ob.setFailedProductionCount(((Integer) row[12]).intValue());
                ob.setFailedPreviewCount(((Integer) row[13]).intValue());
                ob.setLoadedCount(((Integer) row[14]).intValue());
                ob.setPendingCount(((Integer) row[15]).intValue());
                ob.setParkedCount(((Integer) row[16]).intValue());
                ob.setSuccessDeactivatedCount(((Integer) row[17]).intValue());
                ob.setSuccessLoadedProdCount(((Integer) row[18]).intValue());
                ob.setSuccessLoadedPreviewCount(((Integer) row[19]).intValue());
                ob.setTotalPendingCount(((Integer) row[20]).intValue());
                ob.setTotalFailedCount(((Integer) row[21]).intValue());
                totalRowCount = ((Integer) row[22]).intValue();
                if (row[24] != null)
                    ob.setMaxOfferEffectiveEndDt(DateFormats.dateFmt.format((Date) row[24]));
                if (row[25] != null)
                    ob.setMinOfferEffectiveStartDt(DateFormats.dateFmt.format((Date) row[25]));

                ob.setEndedCount(((Integer) row[26]).intValue());
                ob.setCopientDelayCount(((Integer) row[27]).intValue());
                ob.setRejectedCount(((Integer) row[28]).intValue());
                ob.setProcessingCount(((Integer) row[29]).intValue());

                if (row.length > 30) {
                    if (row[30] != null) {
                        ob.setRegionId(row[30].toString());
                    }
                    if (row[31] != null) {
                        ob.setRegionNm(row[31].toString());
                    }
                }

                offerBankTOs.add(ob);
            }
            return new Object[] { totalRowCount, offerBankTOs };
        }

        public Object[] getBankTypes() {
            List<OfferBankTypeTO> offerBankTypes = new ArrayList<OfferBankTypeTO>();
            try {
                String sql = rMgr.get("sql.offer_bank_types");
                SQLQuery query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);

                List typeList = query.list();

                Iterator iter = typeList.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Object[] row = (Object[]) iter.next();
                    OfferBankTypeTO type = new OfferBankTypeTO();
                    type.setOfferBankTypeCd(row[0].toString());
                    type.setOfferBankTypeDesc(row[1].toString());
                    offerBankTypes.add(type);
                }

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                log.error("Error List<OfferBankType> getBankTypes()");
                throw e;
            }
            return new Object[] { offerBankTypes };
        }

        public void updateOfferBank(OfferBank offerBank, Context ctx) {

            String user = (ctx != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName() != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName().length() > 0) ? ((UserContext) ctx)
                    .getUserName() : SharedMessages.getString("user.default");

            offerBank.setLastUpdtTs(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            offerBank.setLastUpdtUserId(user);

            this.makePersistent(offerBank);
        }

        public OfferBank addOfferBank(OfferBank offerBank, Context ctx) {
            String user = (ctx != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName() != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName().length() > 0) ? ((UserContext) ctx)
                    .getUserName() : SharedMessages.getString("user.default");
            Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            offerBank.setLastUpdtTs(now);
            offerBank.setLastUpdtUserId(user);
            offerBank.setCreationUserId(user);
            offerBank.setCreationTs(now);

            return this.insert(offerBank);
        }

        public int updateCurrentBankStatus(OfferBank offerBank, Context ctx) {
            String sql = rMgr.get("sql.update_current_bank_status");
            SQLQuery query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.setParameter("offer_bank_id", offerBank.getOfferBankId());
            return query.executeUpdate();
        }

        public void insertBankStatus(OfferBank offerBank, short newStatusId, Context ctx) {
            String user = (ctx != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName() != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName().length() > 0) ? ((UserContext) ctx)
                    .getUserName() : SharedMessages.getString("user.default");
            OfferBankStatus offerBankStatus = new OfferBankStatus();
            OfferBankStatusId offerBankStatusId = new OfferBankStatusId();
            Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            offerBankStatusId.setOfferBankId(offerBank.getOfferBankId());
            offerBankStatusId.setEffectiveStartDt(now);
            offerBankStatus.setId(offerBankStatusId);
            offerBankStatus.setCreationTs(now);
            offerBankStatus.setCreationUserId(user);
            offerBankStatus.setEffectiveEndDt(null);
            offerBankStatus.setLastUpdtTs(now);
            offerBankStatus.setLastUpdtUserId(user);

            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(offerBankStatus);
        }

        /*public void addOfferBankRegions(List<OfferBankCluster> obRegionList, Context ctx) {
            String user = (ctx != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName() != null && ((UserContext) ctx).getUserName().length() > 0) ? ((UserContext) ctx)
                    .getUserName() : SharedMessages.getString("user.default");
            Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

            for (OfferBankCluster obc : obRegionList) {
                obc.setCreationUserId(user);
                obc.setCreationTs(now);
                obc.setLastUpdtTs(now);
                obc.setLastUpdtUserId(user);

                this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obc);
            }
        }*/
    }
```

and the xml file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>    
    <sql>

        <offer_bank_get_banks>
            select * from (
                select 
                    ob.offer_bank_id
                    , ob.promotional_period_id
                    , ob.offer_bank_nm
                    , obst.offer_bank_status_type_dsc
                    , ob.effective_start_dt
                    , ob.effective_end_dt
                    , obt.offer_bank_type_dsc
                    , obt.offer_bank_type_cd
                    , pp.promotional_period_nm
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'ED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as editing_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'FD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as failed_deactive_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in ('FP', 'FI') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as failed_production_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'FV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as failed_preview_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'LD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as loaded_count                 
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in ('PE', 'PS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pending_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'PK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as parked_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'SD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as successfully_deactivated_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in ('SP','PI') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as successfully_loaded_to_prod_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd = 'SV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as successfully_loaded_to_preview_count                
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in ('LD','PE','PS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_pending_count        
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in ('FD','FP','FV','FR','FI') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as failed_count
                    , COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) as total_rows
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ob.effective_end_dt desc) as row_nbr   
                    , MAX(a.offer_effective_end_dt)as max_offer_effective_end_dt
                    , MIN(a.offer_effective_start_dt)as min_offer_effective_start_dt
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in('AR','SR','SD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ended_count  
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in('CD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as copient_delay_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in('SR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rejected_count
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN a.offer_status_type_cd in('LV', 'GV', 'CD', 'GA', 'GC', 'GD', 'GI', 'GP', 'GR', 'LA', 'LI', 'LP', 'LR', 'LV', 'LE')
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as processing_count
                from 
                    ${sql.database}.offer_bank ob
                    INNER JOIN ${sql.database}.offer_bank_status obs
                    ON ob.offer_bank_id = obs.offer_bank_id
                    INNER JOIN ${sql.database}.offer_bank_status_type obst
                    ON obs.offer_bank_status_type_cd = obst.offer_bank_status_type_cd
                    INNER JOIN ${sql.database}.promotional_period pp
                    ON ob.promotional_period_id = pp.promotional_period_id
                    INNER JOIN ${sql.database}.offer_bank_type obt
                    ON ob.offer_bank_type_cd = obt.offer_bank_type_cd               
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                        (Select 
                            o.offer_id
                            , o.offer_bank_id
                            , ost.offer_status_type_cd
                            , o.offer_effective_end_dt
                            , o.offer_effective_start_dt
                         from 
                            ${sql.database}.offer o                        
                            INNER JOIN ${sql.database}.offer_status os
                            ON o.offer_id = os.offer_id
                            INNER JOIN ${sql.database}.offer_status_type ost
                            ON os.offer_status_type_cd = ost.offer_status_type_cd
                            AND os.effective_end_dt is null
                        ) a
                    ON ob.offer_bank_id = a.offer_bank_id
                where
                    obs.effective_end_dt is null     
         </offer_bank_get_banks>
```

and error stack being:

```
20:52:16,069 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ORA-00972: identifier is too long

20:52:16,070 ERROR OfferBankDaoHibernateImpl:77 - Error getOfferBanks(List<Long> offerBankTypes ,int startPos, int endPos, List<Long> statusIds)
Jul 19, 2013 8:52:16 PM org.restlet.resource.UniformResource doCatch
WARNING: Exception or error caught in resource
```

My code is breaking at OfferBankDaoHibernateImpl. To me it seems the method getOfferBanks(List offerBankTypes ,int startPos, int endPos, List statusIds) is breaking. If anyone has come across a similar situation, it will help?

Comment: What type is your id field? And what are you giving it?

Comment: which field? can you be specific?

Answer (score 1):

`ORA-00972: identifier is too long` tells you what the issue is. The [max length of an identifier is 30 characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#sthref727) in Oracle, and you have a couple aliases that are longer than 30 characters. For example, `successfully_loaded_to_prod_count` is 33 characters.

Comment: Hi, thanks, Now when I fixed the character problem, it says this:

Comment: @Java_stack1 it says what?

Comment: 22:03:18,460 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

22:03:18,462 ERROR OfferBankDaoHibernateImpl:77 - Error getOfferBanks(List<Long> offerBankTypes ,int startPos, int endPos, List<Long> statusIds)

Comment: Btw, I am new to Oracle. I have only decreased the number of characters in identifier when I said I fixed identifier issue? Do you think I may have broken the table/view simply reducing characters in hibernateImpl.xml? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only changed the aliases that were longer than 30 characters, then that shouldn't be the issue--they're just aliases--you can name them whatever you want. Since the issue is with your SQL, not the Java class, I would recommend trying to run the SQL statement by itself (via sqlplus or SQL Developer) and focus on getting that working _first_. ORA-00942 means that it cannot find a table for one of the table names in your query, double check them. Google the ORA error codes for more information on what causes them.

Comment: [ORA-00942](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php) could also mean that the user you are connecting with doesn't have visibility to one or more of the tables in the query

Comment: No that is not the case. I am the user and can see the tables. I am trying to the query and find out whats wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes by running the query individually, I was getting the same error: table or view does not exist.

Comment: Hi, I managed to run the query. However there are still the same errors:

Comment: 12:02:26,470 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist